# Convert pdf file to epub

Tags: pdf, conversion, epub, ebooks

Is to possible to convert pdf file to epub format without errors? Is there some application in Linux that can do it? I found only Ecub and Calibre which give bad results or fail.

A command-line application is sufficient.

It's an ordinary pdf (not scanned), so OCR is not needed.

Comment: If calibre fails you could use the fact that ePub is just a couple of xhtml files inside a zip. So you could play with pdftohtml or pdftotext and then pack the result into a ePub file.

Answer (score 8):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) would be my best suggestion, though it's far from perfect.

The linux version comes with both a GUI interface, and various command line tools. See [ebook-convert](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html):

`ebook-convert file.pdf file.epub`

Comment: I'm sorry, Calibre is another one I tried but I forgot it's name. Now I confirmed that this failed. I tried to open the result with my `Aldiko` reader.

Comment: I would file a bug report in its issue tracker: they put out a new version every week, and are quick to respond in general, I've found.

Comment: But I don't know what error happened, can I test the file.epub and see where is the problem?

Comment: Calibre has a forum at MobileRead.com -- you might ask there.